# Fedora 17 : grub prompt : Cannot boot

Tags: fedora, boot, grub

I have a dual boot - Windows7 and Fedora16. I deleted one of the Windows7 partition and now
Fedora16 cannot boot. However using

```
configfile (hd0,5)/boot/grub/grub.conf
```

I could get back the options menu and I could boot into windows however if I boot into Fedora I get `Error 17 : Cannout mount selected partition.`

I was ale to run it in emergency mode by changing `root(hd0,7)` to `root(hd0,5)`.then the disaster happen. In trying to save the grub config file I executed the following command which I saw on some forum

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

now I cant even boot into windows. If I run

```
configfile (hd0,5)/boot/grub/grub.conf
```

I again get back the grub prompt. I have some important papers in the linux partitition which I want back.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want your documents back, then you can easily do it by booting the system from a **LiveCD** or **LiveUSB**, and then you will be able to access your important files and backup them to another removable media.

Best option is use a distro of Linux, Download it, make a Bootable CD, then restart the system with the LiveCD.

To boot from LiveCD you might need to change the BIOS boot Order. (Learn [here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ss/bootorderchange.htm) to change it)

**Useful Links:**

- Steps to [Use Make Ubuntu LiveCD and Use it to recover data](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/use-ubuntu-live-cd-to-backup-files-from-your-dead-windows-computer/).
- [**How-To** LiveCD Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD#How-To_LiveCD_Ubuntu)

**CAUTION:**
You should NOT write to the failed device, as it can worsen the situation, and overwrite existant data.
Be certain that the "live" cd does not automatically mount any partition or swap space.